# How to create own Back/Forward buttons in xul?

Tags: javascript, browser, firefox-addon, xul, xulrunner

Trying to create my own Back/Forward buttons in xul.

My Code:

```
<label value=" ❀ Back " id="back_button" style="-moz-border-radius: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -khtml-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px;background:#C93E1D; width:100px; color:white;" onclick="history.go(-1);"></label>
```

Also tried history.back() onclick of xul button. But nothing happened.

```
<button label="back" oncommand="history.back();"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
document.getElementById("main-browser").webNavigation.goBack();
```